# Gitlab runner cache miss file after stage complete

Tags: spring, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

**Summary**

My gitlab-ci.yml has 3 stage for deploy an application to okd pod
Application running spring boot on tomcat:8
Sometimes, the cache.zip is not update after stage complete so that the next step can't run correctly

**Steps to reproduce**

My gitlab-ci run the following stage

Stage 1: run test compile ---> OK

Stage 2: package war file as output for deploy ---> Gitlab-ci log show success but the cache.zip has not war file (just sometimes cache.zip not have war file, sometimes it run correctly)

Stage 3: Deploy war file to pod ---> Because of war file not exists in cache.zip, script error -> failed

*.gitlab-ci.yml*

```
image: openshift/origin-cli

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - staging

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
    - target
    - artifact

validate:jdk8:
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'mvn test-compile'
  only:
    - master
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

verify:jdk8:
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'mvn verify'
    - 'mvn package' # =====> this command generate war file
  only:
    - master
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

staging:
  script:
    - "mkdir -p artifact"
    - "cp ./target/*.war ./artifact/" # ======> Sometimes error at this line because of previous step not add war file into cache
    - "oc start-build $APP"
    - "rm -rf ./target/* && rm -rf ./artifact/*" # Remove war & class file, only cache m2 lib
  stage: staging
  variables:
    APP: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://$CI_PROJECT_NAME-staging.$OPENSHIFT_DOMAIN
  only:
    - master
```

**Actual behavior**
Sometimes cache not have war file after test stage complete (is this depends on war file size?)

**Expected behavior**
War file update into cache after test stage for staging stage deploy

**Relevant logs and/or screenshots**

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SzS2.png)

**job log**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.7.0 (943fc252)
  on gitlab-runner-node1 y6awygsj
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:01
Using Docker executor with image openshift/origin-cli ...
Using locally found image version due to if-not-present pull policy
Using docker image sha256:7ebb6be01117a50344d63f77c385a13302afecd33480b97c36a518d4f5ebc25a for openshift/origin-cli with digest docker.io/openshift/origin-cli@sha256:509e052d0f2d531b666b7da9fa49c5558c76ce5d286456f0859c0a49b16d6bf2 ...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on runner-y6awygsj-project-489-concurrent-0 via gitlab.runner.node1...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/my-project/.git/
Checking out b4c97428 as master...
Removing .m2/
Removing artifact/
Removing target/
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
00:05
Checking cache for default-23...
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
$ mkdir -p artifact
$ cp ./target/*.war ./artifact/
cp: cannot stat './target/*.war': No such file or directory
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

**Environment description**

*config.toml*

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab-runner-node1"
  url = "https://gitlab.mycompany.vn/"
  token = "y6awygsj9zks18nU6PDt"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    dns = ["192.168.100.1"]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/mnt/nfs/nfsshare-gitlab/cache:/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    pull_policy = "if-not-present"
```

**Used GitLab Runner version**

Version:      13.7.0

Git revision: 943fc252

Git branch:   13-7-stable

GO version:   go1.13.8

Built:        2020-12-21T13:47:06+0000

OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

**Possible fixes**

Re-run test stage until cache has war file

Comment: Could it be that the jobs are executed on different runners? Btw, `mvn verify` already includes the `package` phase so the `mvn package` is not needed.

Comment: @slauth my system has 2 runners and using same nfs share directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go step by step.

First, regarding how to manage the files between stages.

It's true that you could directly access to the files between jobs and stages if both run on the same environment, but that's not always the case (even if both runners are using the same nfs share directory) and you should use `artifacts` for that.

When you define an `artifact` within a job, you're specifying a list of files that are attached to the job when it succeeds, fails or always, depending on the configuration you have.

By default, all `artifacts` from previous stages are passed to each job, but in any case you can use `dependencies` to also define from which jobs you want to fetch artifacts from.

So basically you should use the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: openshift/origin-cli

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - staging

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

validate:jdk8:
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'mvn test-compile'
  only:
    - master
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

verify:jdk8:
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'mvn verify' # =====> verify already includes: validate, compile, test and package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/[YOUR_APP_NAME].war
  only:
    - master
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

staging:
  dependencies:
    - verify:jdk8
  script:
    - "mkdir -p artifact"
    - "cp ./target/[YOUR_APP_NAME].war ./artifact/"
    - "oc start-build $APP"
  stage: staging
  variables:
    APP: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://$CI_PROJECT_NAME-staging.$OPENSHIFT_DOMAIN
  only:
    - master
```

Also, notice that I deleted the `mvn package` instruction. I would recommend you to take a look into the [**Build Lifecycle Basics of Maven**](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#build-lifecycle-basics).

Comment: Not a bad ideal but can't resolve my problem because if config artifact instead of cache, gitlab-runner will upload artifacts file to gitlab server (too large and not good for gitlab's server performance), please reference image: https://imgur.com/a/0oW0RdF

Comment: Well of course it was a proposal taking into account that I don't know the actual name of your generated artifact. You should only keep that one `whatever.jar` and not all the compiled classes.

Comment: Only deployed war(or jar) file have around 500MB+ and still too large to upload it as artifact. But in other way, the requirement told that we need to keep all maven lib for the next cycle (to prevent re-download from internet)

Comment: The downloaded dependencies from Maven aren't stored in `target` but in `.m2/repository`, that's why I didn't disable that one from your defined cache. But as you can see your `cache` is local, so if you change between runners even with the same filesystem it won't restore it. That's not an issue for dependencies, which are checked, but it is for resultant artifacts. So you need to choose: you configure a shared cache, you set up a registry where you upload your WAR or you configure it as an GitLab CI `artifact`; but with two runners and a local cache it won't work.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Campos, i understood, but this problem not appear in every run, just sometime.

Comment: Your cache will be stored in a ZIP file under `/mnt/nfs/nfsshare-gitlab/cache/[PROJECT_DIRECTORY]/cache.zip` and will be loaded before the job execution and stored afterwards. If any other job uses that cache between `verify:jdk8` and `staging`, the cache will be overwritten, and then you'll have the problem. But of course it could be that you're ZIP is untouched between jobs, so it will work. As I'm telling you, you shouldn't use the `cache` for sharing artifacts between stages. When I say it won't work, I mean in the 100% of cases.